# How to mass copy the title of each node to a taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views, external-scripts

I need to copy the title of nodes to its taxonomy term.
I have the following content type

- Title - text
- Body - text
- Taxonomy term - (currently empty)

I want to copy the "Title" ---> "Taxonomy term" for each node.
How can I do this?

I understand that VBO with som php-snippet could solve this but I am no programmer. Any suggestions about a working snippet or other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_buk_operations) module to create a custom rule component, which you then use as a custom VBO action.

For way more details on this combination, have a look at my answer to "[How to bulk update select list fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192419/how-to-bulk-update-select-list-fields/192529#192529)".

In your case, the custom Rules Component should look pretty similar to this:

```
{ "rules_set_an_initial_value_for_a_term_field" : {
    "LABEL" : "Set an initial value for a term field",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "node" : { "label" : "Node", "type" : "node" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_yourfield" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-yourfield" ], "value" : "HereGoesTheTitle" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details to further explain the above example:

- adapt the machinename of `field_yourfield` to the machine name for your taxonomy term field.
- replace the (hardcoded) `HereGoesTheTitle` value in the Rules Action by the token like `node:title` (which for sure wil be available).
- I'm assuming your taxonomy term is a single value field, if it is a multi value field, then replace the action with a similar one to "Add an item to a list" (related to your multi value field).

PS: no need at all for any custom PHP code when using this approach.