# How to merge multiple fields into one, across multiple content types?

Tags: 7, database

I'm updating some old Drupal 7 sites, and I need to merge a number of fields across multiple content types.

For example, I have the *field_article_body*, *field_page_body*, and *field_event_body* fields that needs to be merged into the core *body* field, or the *field_article_image*, *field_page_image*, and *field_event_image* fields that need to be merged into the *field_image* field.

I am hoping there is some solution which can assist me in combining these fields, or alternatively some SQL magic which an expert can help me with.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (to build a list of nodes to be updated) and a combination of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_buk_operations) (to mass update such lists) you should be able to perform the merge of those fields.

Refer to my answer to "[How to bulk update select list fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192419/how-to-bulk-update-select-list-fields/192529#192529)" for an example with way more details about that, which is about a variation of your scenario (ie change the value of an existing field, while you want to "copy" the value of an existing field to the value of a new field).

For your case, this example of a **Rules Component** (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format) should be close to one of the Rules Components you'd need for your "field_image":

```
{ "rules_set_an_initial_value_for_image_field" : {
    "LABEL" : "Set an initial value for image field",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "node" : { "label" : "Node", "type" : "node" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_article_image" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-image" ], "value" : [ "field_article_image" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note**: by using an approach with modules such as above (instead of SQL magic), you do have the advantage that all possible relatic magic will happen automagically and behind the scenes (eg: create a new revision of such nodes). And it avoids your Drupal database gets corrupted because "you forgot some table".

Comment: Thank you. This was just the answer was looking for. The video mentioned in your linked answer has moved to https://drupalize.me/videos/using-rules-components-vbo?p=1157

Comment: Merci (oeps: thank you) @MrPaulDriver, for the accept, and +1 ... About the video in the linked answer: it can also be found at "[Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo)", where it is located including the correct [attribution](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) to famous "Johan Falk" (together with dozens of similar links to other commonly known videos from the same author, about Views, Flag, etc).