# How to delete all Drupal content owned by a particular user?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, users

It seems like there should be a drush command to achieve this, but I cannot find one. I am not clever enough to fashion an SQL query that will delete all nodes owned by a user as well as clean up all the field and revision data.

Please let me know if anyone has any solutions (other than deleting the user's account).

Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible alternative to achieve what you're trying to do, is to use a combination of modules [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). With these modules in place, you could simply create a view of all the nodes "*owned*" by a user, and simply use the out-of-the-box VBO action to "delete an item" (after adding a VBO field like "Bulk operations: Content"). And by creating a similar VBO view, using the VBO field "Bulk operations: Content revision", you can probably also cleanup up the revision data.

If you need more sophisticated business logic to decide about the criteria related to "*owned by a user*", you could add [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to such solution also and implement a variation of the solution described in my answer to "[How to bulk update select list fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192419/how-to-bulk-update-select-list-fields/192529#192529)", i.e.:

- Create a Rules Component with a Rules Condition to checks if the node matches the criteria you're interested in.
- Create a VBO enabled view of all nodes to be checked, whereas you'll use the Rules Component as your custom VBO action.

***Done ...***